# Get information of clicnic near by latitude and longitude in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing php application in codeigniter in which i want to get all clinic and blood bank information near by latitude and longitude , so is there any api which get these information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you need to use [The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

- You need to sign-up for an [API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#api_key)
- This service has its usage limits.

This is how you make a [search request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests) from your API.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=APIKEY
```

#### Explanation (for the above search request):

Searches for Places of type 'food' within a 500m radius of a point in Sydney, Australia, containing the word 'harbour' in their name.

There is a list of supported place types and you can go through them and use it on your application.

[image]

Find the whole list [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)

Comment: Thanks for help, but when execute script then error from google         {
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: Please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/22336836/1003917 and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: when i  create new server api then "The provided API key is expired" this message is come  from google,

Comment: Sadly it seems like you need a business account for that https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/