# Getting Google Maps link from place_id

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-urls

HeIIo, using google map API with search I'm able to find a certain place and then store it's details. However, the array doesn't contain google maps link which would open this place on google maps.

Via API I receive place_id which, as I feel, should be enough to build a full google maps link; however, I can't find a way to do that. Can anyone advise me on how to do that.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm having this same issue in an Android app I'm building.  If the answer below is correct, it seems ridiculous to have to use the returned place_id to create another URL request to get the correct CID

Answer (score 166):

Try below syntax. I hope it helps

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/?q=place_id:ChIJp4JiUCNP0xQR1JaSjpW_Hms
```

Comment: Simple, with no additional request to the server.

Comment: Google maps on android says: `Unsupported link: Google maps can't open this link`

Comment: @KirillKulakov sorry for this.. :(

Comment: Confirmed working solution August 2022

Comment: @slothstronaut It doesn't work on Android. See Kirill Kulakov's answer for an alternative that works on both desktop and mobile. Any string for "query" will work, it doesn't have to be the address.

Comment: Now how do you do it the other way round? Maps page to place_id?

Answer (score 44):

Here is an official url to search for a `placeId` with a fallback to an `address` if the `placeId` does not exist

`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=<address>&query_place_id=<placeId>`

no token required, works on Android, iOS (as well as iOS 11) and web

Comment: Confirmed - works well! The address part is required but doesn't do anything it seems. I was able to enter anything in there and have the lookup still work.

Comment: The address is a backup, if the google place ID will be delete, google maps will fallback to the address. you can try that by providing an invalid place id

Comment: Best solution - on desktop opens Google Maps website, on mobile (Android and iOS) opens Google Maps application.

Comment: This solution works, thanks, but I get "Mixed content" warnings when I eventually land on the listing: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=%3Caddress%3E&query_place_id=ChIJoT5E1FlgLxMR1qP3Z4NRVBY' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.google.com/maps/vt/data=zYuhVnS8JosXRxoH3bbPoEAByijPZHC_yNruvFpujaxqT6-OKmrS1cV2ft0f8dQNh7_HX2epahFbnLuLDgS39EdmrW_ZHt-eAfKRxDSXoaOf3BHtn5RaLfE26v_G06ja4OLDXnSi_nubeVjJPp0'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: query is required based on the docs https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started

Answer (score 13):

There is a way of always getting the right URL but it does require an additional request.

You can use the place_id to get the place details with
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=YOURAPIKEY&placeid=THEPLACEID`

The response from that has a ['result']['url'] field which always opens up the right place. 
eg. `https://maps.google.com/?cid=10254754059248426663`

Comment: I'm getting INVALID REQUEST with that

Comment: You need to use ServerAPIKey. Loot at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24235630/4457396

Answer (score 12):

There is no documentation for the expected parameters on https://www.google.com/maps/place , so this may only be a workaround(at least it currently works for me).

The following URL-format seems to give the desired result in  most cases:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/[place-name]/@[latitude],[longitude],[zoom]z/
```

You may create this URL based on the place-name and the place-geometry

```js
function initialize() {
  var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('pac'));
  google.maps.event.addListener(ac, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = this.getPlace(),
      link = document.getElementById('link');
    if (!place.geometry) {
      link.textContent = '';
    } else {
      var zoom = 17,
        url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/' +
        encodeURIComponent(place.name) + '/@' +
        place.geometry.location.toUrlValue() + ',' +
        zoom + 'z/';
      link.href = link.textContent = url;

    }

  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places">
</script>
<input id="pac" />
<br/>
<a id="link"  href="" target="_blank"></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with an iOS app redirecting users to the desired place (returned from `nearbysearch` API) in google maps.

They mentioned above:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/?q=place_id:ChIJp4JiUCNP0xQR1JaSjpW_Hms
```

If you open this link in your browser, it will show a place on the google map website.

But if you try to open this link on a mobile phone, it will open the google map application instead (if it exists on the user's phone) and not redirect to safari.
Also, the google map application doesn't show the place (**that link will work on the browser only**).

After testing many ways for creating a link to work both in the google map application and browser, the best way is to show a place is just passing `location` and `place_id` within the link.

```
let url = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=\(placeLatitude)%2C\(placeLongitude)&query_place_id=\(placeId)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use google embed API, and take src as a link:
eg:

```
 https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY
  &q=place_id:YOUR_PLACE_ID
```

Docs:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#place_mode

Comment: This requires an API key, which isn't ideal for a lot of people.

Answer (score 1):

You can use google embed API, and take src as a link: eg:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me without place_id

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/<search term>/@<coordinates>,<zoom level>z
```

Example

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/Jouvay+Night+Club/@40.6961111,-73.8041667,15z
```