# Link to Google Maps Directions using place_id

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-maps-urls

I have 2 Place IDs I've obtained via the Google Places API, and want to display a link to the Google Maps app for directions between those 2 places.

I see that it's possible to do this with 2 addresses based on the answer at [Current Location - Google Maps - Link to Directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042283/current-location-google-maps-link-to-directions) using the `saddr` and `daddr` query parameters

I also see that it's possible to link to a map with a place ID by prefixing `place_id:...` in the `q` query parameter from this answer at [Getting Google Maps link from place_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857150/getting-google-maps-link-from-place-id)

Is there a way to have a **directions** link with the Google **place_id**? I tried a URL like:
`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/place_id:ChIJp4JiUCNP0xQR1JaSjpW_Hms/place_id:ChIJp4JiUCNP0xQR1JaSjpW_Hms` and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Have you tried the [Embed API directions mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode)?

Comment: Directly going to the URL `https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=MY_API_KEY&origin=Oslo+Norway&destination=Telemark+Norway&avoid=tolls|highways` gives the error: "The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to open Google Maps directions mode with place IDs you have to use [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action). The Google Maps URLs in directions mode support parameters `origin_place_id` and `destination_place_id`.

Create the following URL for example (note that origin and destination parameters are also mandatory as per documentation)

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Yukar%C4%B1%20Bah%C3%A7elievler%2C%2070.%20Sk.%2017%2FB%2C%2006490%20%C3%87ankaya%2FAnkara%2C%20Turkey&origin_place_id=ChIJp4JiUCNP0xQR1JaSjpW_Hms&destination=Be%C5%9Fikkaya%2C%202044%2F1.%20Sk.%2C%2006230%20Alt%C4%B1nda%C4%9F%2FAnkara%2C%20Turqu%C3%ADa&destination_place_id=ChIJn-ZptRFT0xQRGUyoJX2s8Wc`

Have a look at the documentation for further details.

I hope this helps!