# Where should google maps geocoding server key be put?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I have an android application and I want to use google maps geocoding API. I see in their guides that you must use a **server key**. However, according to their guides, a server key is something that should be kept on the server, unexposed, and not in the client (in my case, the app itself).
Therefore, my question is, Am I using it the right way? Should I just put my server key in my AndroidManifest.xml file? If not, where? Is it possible to use google map geocoding api from withing the app? if so, what's the deal with the server key?

Thanks!

Comment: Official recommendation from Google in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516858/this-ip-site-or-mobile-application-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-key

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know for using the maps you need an **Android key** and not the server key.
That is my reality (I have maps in my app).