# Google api key not working

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places-api

When I try to test my google api key with this form:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

I use the exact code but change the api key, 
it keeps telling me:

```
Foutcode: InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError
```

I registered my key at my google developer console.  Already looked at this conversation: [This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933247/this-ip-site-or-mobile-application-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-key) but then it still doesn't work.

But when I do a get request like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=netherlands&key=myapicod
```

It works? I really don't understand it anymore.....

Comment: I assume the code is run on a web page that the API key is registered for

Comment: @Jaromanda In the conversation mentioned above they are saying: Enter your IP Address on the field and if you have more ip addresses, you can just add on every single line.NOTE: Enter the IP Address only when you want to use it for your testing purpose. Else leave the IP Address section blank.

Comment: yeah ... not sure how that relates to what I said, but, good luck