# This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to plot a route between two locations using the following URL

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" + params + androidKey;
```

where `params` is the latitude and longitude of the the origin and destination and `androidKey` is the Android Key I received from Google Console using my SHA fingerprint. I have enabled Google Maps Android API, Google Places API for Android, Google Places API Web Service amongst others, however I'm still getting the following response when I try running the application on my phone

```
This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address
```

I tried using Server Key which resulted in the following response

```
This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console
```

Could someone please help?
Thanks

Comment: Make sure you TURN ON Places API services in console

Comment: please refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933247/this-ip-site-or-mobile-application-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-key

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have referred to all the StackOverflow questions regarding the issue however the issue remains.

Comment: @user1232138: check my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21933247/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you have enabled `Google Maps Directions API` in Google Api console.
2. You have to use your `Server_key`

   eg: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=Server_key

I got the response only after enabling the APi in google api console.