# Get authorization for IP to use an API key

Tags: api, google-places-api

I refer to a answer given by Mike20132013 on 
[This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933247/this-ip-site-or-mobile-application-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-key?answertab=active#tab-top).

Mike in point 5 you say:
Once you are done, click create and your new Server Key will be generated and you can then add that server key to your URL.

Sorry, I am lost here. I have created a server key but to which URL are you referring to? Where exactly do I enter this URL please? I have bought the Google Reviews Plugin and I get the error message 
"REQUEST_DENIED: This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 46.249.199.28, with empty referer" on my website.
My host has referred me to your answer.

Then you say

"Last thing is that, instead of putting the sensor=true in the middle of the URL, you can add it in the end like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=yourlatitude,yourlongitude&radius=5000&key=SERVERKEY&sensor=true"

I have no idea where to input this.

Comment: @Mike20132013. I am new here and can therefore only create my own new question

Comment: Please ask question at his above thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933247/this-ip-site-or-mobile-application-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-key)

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam I am really sorry about doing this way. Being new does not allow me with my limited credits to comment on his post. If it is just asking a question, how do I keep it in his thread? Your assistance will be greatly appreciated, since of certainly I want to do it the right way

Answer (score 0):

Easy part first: just omit the `sensor` parameter entirely.  As the documentation says:

> [The Google Places API previously required that you include the sensor parameter to indicate whether your application used a sensor to determine the user's location. This parameter is no longer required.](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#Sensor)

For the REQUEST_DENIED error, please go to the Google Developers Console and ensure that:

1. you are using a **Server** key, not a **Browser** key or similar.
2. you have the Google Places API Web Service enabled (rather than e.g. Google Places API for Android).
3. your Server key either has a **blank** field for the IP addresses that may use it, or that the IP addresses field matches your IP (46.249.199.28).

The [Get a Key](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key) part of the Google Places API Web Service documentation walks you through creating an appropriately configured API key.