# This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key Request received from IP address 163.85.31.144, with empty referer

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to connect to the google places api but it gives me error:
 "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 183.87.41.123, with empty referer",   "predictions" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}

I have used all three types of API but it isn't working first i used Android key , than i used Browser key and now i am using server key but no result!

here is my code:

```
package com.astro.famouspandit.Activities.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.astro.famouspandit.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Location extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private EditText mEdttxtCity;
    private String input;
     String API_KEY;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);
         //API_KEY = "sdlflfNK-sldkfndlsnfdslanflsdn";
         API_KEY = "fsdnflsdnflnflsdnfldsnfldnfldnf";
         //browser key API_KEY = "askjskfdskjfssdkfksdjbfsdk-csdkfdskn";

        mEdttxtCity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttxtCity);
        mEdttxtCity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                 input =  mEdttxtCity.getText().toString();
                if (input.length() >3) {

                    SearchPlacesTask   searchplacesTask = new SearchPlacesTask();
                    searchplacesTask.execute();


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }



        });




    }
    private class SearchPlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.d("SearchPlacesTask Called","");

        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console

            String key = "key="+API_KEY;


            try {
                input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf-8");
                Log.e("input String : ","input" + input);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // place type to be searched
            String types = "types=geocode";

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "language=en";

                /*// Building the parameters to the web service
                String parameters = input + "&" + types + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;*/


            // Building the parameters to the web service

            String parameters = input + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;


            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service

            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"
                    + output + "?" + parameters;

            Log.d("Final URL Google API : ","url" + url);
            //            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/location=13.758662,100.496443" + output + "?" + parameters;

            try {
                // Fetching the data from we service
                data = downloadUrlsearch(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());

            }

            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

//YOUR JSON DATA HERE.
//NOW YOU CAN PARSE.


        }
    }

    private String downloadUrlsearch(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();


            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            Log.d("data: ","" + data);

            br.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
//            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {

            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21933247/608639)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you haven't made your API specific to some package or signature when generating it?

Comment: can you elaborate ? i have used my ip address for creating server key , i used package name com.astro.woild as the package for craeting browser key

Comment: can you tell me which key type i have to use ?

Comment: you have to generate android key when you click "create credentials". Furthermore, check whether SHA-1 certificate fingerprint is correct when you're mentioning your package name while creating APi key.