# google maps url request gives msg "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key"

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, httprequest, point

I getting this message error from google maps while requesting url for source and destination point. Does any one know about it. Please share your experience.

> {
>       "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address
>   103.24.99.82, with empty referer",
>
> "routes" : [],    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
>
> }

url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=24.878353,67.064308&destination=24.909353,67.085304&sensor=false&avoid=highways&mode=driving&key={key_value_here}

Comment: You don't mean that you enter your Google API key with those curly brackets, do you?

Comment: no, not with curly brackets . i know this thing. @ElTomato

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21933247/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call google directions api from a project with same bundle id associated with the key you created

Comment: yes i have done this too.

Comment: you got this result in xcode console or web browser?

Comment: web browser. in console its nil.

Comment: strange behaviour i observe now you click above url it will give response with data. mean not including my api key. why this happen?

Comment: it's seems there is a wrong with this key , assure it's for directions , or copy past issue

Comment: i think the issue is with url. i have just copy this url from stackOver.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer because the directions API is a web service and bundle restrictions can't be applied!

Answer (score 3):

It may be the reason of IP address got restricted by the Google.

**You can follow below steps to rectify it:**

1. Go to the Google API Console.
2. Select the project that was created for you when you signed up.
3. From the list of API keys, select the key you're using.
4. In the Restrictions section, select IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.).
5. Under Accept requests from these server IP addresses, enter the IP addresses from which your key is to be accepted, one per line. You may also enter a subnet using CIDR notation (e.g. 192.168.0.0/22).

Comment: I have selected iOS apps which requires bundle name. and i don't wanna restrict it just on IP. then?