# Google places autocomplete API is not working in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

My Google Autocomplete API is worked well few mins ago. But suddenly it start showing error 
"This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 220.225.217.35, with empty referer"

how to fix this?

Comment: Google gave me this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933247/this-ip-site-or-mobile-application-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-key

But if it worked before and you didn't change anything, I don't know any further... (Maybe too many requests, but I guess it would return a different message then)

Comment: Please include the actual code which is calling the Google service.  What restrictions do you have on your API key?