# This site is not authorized

Tags: android, google-nearby

Please help me!

I am creating find near by places application in android, when i request for places using Unrestricted key. It will response me fully.

But after restricting Key with my project name, `Released SHA1` and `Debug SHA1`
it will not responding and give me error.
"This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.
Ask Question".

- I am requesting using HttpURLConnection,
- My request code is

  ```
  StringBuilder googlePlaceUrl = new StringBuilder 
  ("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json? 
    location=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&rankby=distance&type="+ 
    nearbyPlace +"&key=xxxxxxxxxxx");
  ```

  In my manifest

  ```
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="xxxxxxxxx" />
  ```

I am not expecting this answer.

```
{ "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 103.24.99.82, with empty referer",
"routes" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: So you are calling a Web API and configured your key to be Android only?. Shouldn't you be using the [Places SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/signup)?

Comment: Have you Checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933247/this-ip-site-or-mobile-application-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-key ?

Comment: Please review the types of API keys in [Using Google Maps API FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#using-google-maps-apis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). Select your project and and click on the API Key you have created.

In that you will find Key Restriction. Please check restriction none. If you want to select Android then you need to add the `package name` of the Application and the `SHA1 key`. Make sure you entered the correct package name and SHA1 Key. If you have entered SHA1 key of your PC then it will not work in another pc if you are working in team. For that you need to add another SHA1 Key of that particular PC.

[image]

Comment: But i have to restrict my key, coz i want to publish this. Without restriction it works fine.

Comment: Then please check you have entered the correct SHA1 Key and package name. Please add SHA1 key of relese keystore and sign apk with that keystore

Comment: After creating keystore successfully using 
keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore "MYPATH/file.jks"
I am still getting same error :(
Should i use Unrestricted key and upload it?

Comment: Google documentation is just saying to replaces the URL and key with your API KEY. I don't know what is difference between API key and Server Key.