# Request Denied when request Direction API ANDROID

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, routes, polyline

I want make a route in maps, so i use Direction API from google maps, but i always get REQUEST DENIED & This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.

I already change to none restriction, and already make the new project, but got same response, so what is the problem ?

i use this library
https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary
Thanks.

**This is the log message**

[image: This is the log message]

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems fitting:

**"This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key"**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24235630/5644761

Answer (score 0):

The API key is restricted to some IP and the one you are connecting with is not white listed you need to add it into the [console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials), select the API key then add the IP adresse .[image]