# Android app: This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, directions

In my app I need to calculate and to display the route to a specified location. All work perfect on debug mode, but on release mode the route can't be calculated and get the next error message:

> This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.

I need to get a payed plan to can do that? Isn't to clear for me when read the documentation from google website.

Any idea how to fix my problem?

Comment: when you make a release build of your source, because of changing sign key the api not work with old sign key, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933247/this-ip-site-or-mobile-application-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-key

Comment: what to do to use right sign key?

Comment: I have read again documentation and I am sure that need to subscribe to a billing plan.

Comment: of course you need to use billing plan,  but for introduce your app in console you must add release and debug keystore as well. hope to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use billing plan for release, but for introduce your app in console you must add release and debug keystore as well